# Integer solution to the following root

Tags: number-theory

If $a,b\in\Bbb{N}$, then what is the smallest non-trivial solution to this equation?

$$\frac{\lfloor100{\sqrt[3]{a}}\rfloor}{100}+\frac{1}{100}=b$$

So I want the answer like this:

$a=\text{something}$

$b=\text{something else}$

No proofs necessary (but one might help!)

Thank you very much. This question has been sitting on my chest for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by non-trivial, but: the left-hand side will be an integer precisely when $\lfloor 100\sqrt[3]a \rfloor$ is congruent to $99$ modulo $100$. This is the same as asking that the first two digits of $\sqrt[3]a$ to the right of the decimal point equal $99$. A simple computer search reveals that the smallest such positive $a$ is $a=215$ (for which $b=6$). The set of such positive integers $a$ has density $0.01$ among the positive integers, since the fractional part of $\sqrt[3]a$ is asymptotically equidistributed modulo $1$; and every $b\ge6$ will be part of solutions—indeed, asymptotically $0.03b^2$ solutions.

Comment: It checks out. Nice work